# paypal force user to create account even when they choose "Don't have a PayPal account"

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

I use IPN in my website. The request is sent to https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr .   It works fine before.

Few weeks ago I notice that even the user choose to pay without paypal account, they are forced to create an account.   As it is showed in the first picture.  At the bottom of that page, it asks the user to create an account.  They can not skip it.

But if I change the country to China (in the first picture, I change the country to China), then the page layout is changed to the old version.  As it is show in the second picture.   In this page, the user do not need to create an account to make the payment.

My question is how can I go to the old page layout directly?

[image: This is the new payment page]

[image: This is the page I prefer]

Comment: That's probably a good question for paypal support.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be addressed to PayPal.

Comment: I contacted paypal.  They do not response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I called paypal, this is their issue and they said they are aware of it, no ETA.  They said they have not emailed clients affected by this at all.  I ran into the same issue with my clients, this blows...
-Quentin